I am attempting to print out a list of prime numbers, but nothing is printing out, what is wrong / what could I change in my code?
I have written an assembly program where my goal is to print out prime numbers the amount of times that the user enters. The user only has to enter one number, say, 15, and the first 15 prime numbers will be printed. The range the user can enter in is between 1 and 200.
My error-catching works, so entering anything below 1 or above 200 re-prompts for another number, but when I enter a number in the correct range that is supposed to be valid, nothing is printed out and the program pretty much stops in its tracks, but does not end. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the code I have as of right now.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

; Constant definitions
LOWER_BOUND = 1
UPPER_BOUND = 200

.data
    ; All text prompts and statements
    nameAndProgram      BYTE "Prime Numbers Programmed by Norman O'Brien", 13, 10, 0
    promptPt1           BYTE "Enter the number of prime numbers you would like to see.", 13, 10, 0
    promptPt2           BYTE "I'll accept orders for up to 200 primes.", 13, 10, 0 
    enterNumberOf       BYTE "Enter the number of primes to display [1 ... 200]: ", 0
    outOfRange          BYTE "No primes for you! Number out of range. Try again.", 13, 10, 0
    certified           BYTE "Results certified by Norman O'Brien. Goodbye.", 13, 10, 0
    spacer              BYTE "   ", 0       ; This is for separating the prime numbers when it is printed

    ; Variables
    validNum        DWORD 0
    userInput       SDWORD ?

.code
main PROC

    call    introduction
    call    getUserData
    call    showPrimes
    call    farewell

    Invoke ExitProcess,0    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP


introduction PROC
    ; Print the my name and program name
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET nameAndProgram
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    ; Print first part of prompt info
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET promptPt1
    call    WriteString

    ; Print second part of prompt info
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET promptPt2
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    ret
introduction ENDP


getUserData PROC
top:
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET enterNumberOf
    call    WriteString

    call    ReadInt
    MOV     userInput, EAX

    call validate

    MOV     EAX, validNum
    CMP     EAX, 0
    JE      top

    ret
getUserData ENDP


validate PROC
    MOV     EBX, userInput
    CMP     EBX, LOWER_BOUND
    JL      rangeError
    
    CMP     EBX, UPPER_BOUND
    JG      rangeError
    JL      valid

rangeError:
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET outOfRange
    call    WriteString
    JMP     ending

valid:
    MOV     EAX, 1
    MOV     validNum, EAX

ending:
    ret
validate ENDP


showPrimes PROC
    MOV     EBX, userInput  ; set EBX to number of primes
    MOV     ECX, 0          ; counter, start at 0
    MOV     EAX, 2          ; EAX starts at 2 because it is the first prime

printPrime:
    ; checks if the current number is a prime number
    PUSH    EAX             ; push current number to stack
    CALL    isPrime         
    POP     EAX             ; restores number from stack after it is checked by isPrime
    
    CMP     EAX, 1          ; check if the number is prime
    JNE     notPrime        ; if it's not prime, skip displaying
    
    ; display the prime number
    CALL    WriteDec
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET spacer
    call    WriteString
    INC     ECX             ; increment prime count

    ; after 10 primes have been printed, make new line and reset the count
    CMP     ECX, 10         
    JNE     nextPrime       ; go to next prime if 10 have not been displayed
    CALL    CrLf
    MOV     ECX, 0          ; reset count

    CMP     ECX, EBX        ; see if enough primes have been displayed based on the user input (EBX)
    JL      printPrime      ; display the next prime if not
    ret

nextPrime:
    INC     EAX             ; move on to the next number by incrementing EAX
    JMP     printPrime

; if not prime just move on to the next number
notPrime:
    INC     EAX 
    JMP     printPrime

    ret
showPrimes ENDP


isPrime PROC
    MOV     ECX, 2          ; checking for the primes will start at 2

    ; 1 does not count as prime, so jump to notPrime if that is the case
    CMP     EAX, 1      
    JLE     notPrime

checkDivisor:
    ; divide the number in EAX by the current divisor (ECX) and if there is 
    ; no remainder, then the number is not prime, so jump to notPrime
    MOV     EDX, 0
    DIV     ECX
    CMP     EDX, 0
    JE      notPrime

    ; increment the divisor and see if we have checked all possible divisors
    ; when we compare, if total number of divisors is great than the input (ECX > EAX), it's prime
    INC     ECX             
    CMP     ECX, EAX
    JG      prime
    JMP     checkDivisor

notPrime:
    MOV     EAX, 0
    ret

prime:
    MOV     EAX, 1
    ret
isPrime ENDP


farewell PROC
    MOV     EDX, OFFSET certified
    call    WriteString

    ret
farewell ENDP

END main



When/where/how does it go different from a C or Java version of the same algorithm?

You can only store one value in a register at a time -- writing a value to a register clobbers any previous value the register had, with no way of getting it back.
So when you have code like:
    PUSH    EAX             ; push current number to stack
    CALL    isPrime         
    POP     EAX             ; restores number from stack after it is checked by isPrime
    
    CMP     EAX, 1          ; check if the number is prime
    JNE     notPrime        ; if it's not prime, skip displaying

The return value from isPrime (which you test to see if it is 1 and branch if it is not), gets clobbered by the value that you pop.  Since the numbers you are checking are >= 2, this results in the branch always being taken and nothing getting printed.  You have similar clobbering problems with ECX -- used both as a counter in your showPrimes loop and as the divisor in isPrime.
The DIV instruction in isPrime also clobbers EAX, overwriting it with the result of the divide.


My error-catching works, so entering anything below 1 or above 200 re-prompts for another number

Well, not really! There are multiple errors in the validate proc.

If the user enters the UPPER_BOUND itself, that will be considered as a rangeError. It's because you wrote JL valid. The complement to JG is really JLE, but more often we would just write JMP.
And in case of a rangeError, you display a message but you don't actually zero the EAX register and/or store it in validNum. Tip: you don't need this memory-based variable at all. Just inspect EAX upon return.


In the showPrimes proc I see these errors:

You are restoring the current number from the stack too early! Inspecting the return value from isPrime must come first:
          push eax
          call isPrime     ; -> EAX=[0,1]
          test eax, eax
          pop  eax
          jz   notPrime


You are using ECX to count prime numbers, but you forget that the isPrime proc will use ECX for its own purposes too. So one proc or the other will have to preserve the value, or you could opt to select some non-conflicting registers.

The test to see if enough primes have been displayed based on the user input comes too late, and the logic for grouping per ten numbers is heavily flawed. See next improved version:
          inc  ecx       ; Finished printing another prime
          dec  ebx
          jz   done
          cmp  ecx, 10         
          jne  next
          call CrLf
          xor  ecx, ecx  ; reset count
  notPrime:
  next:   inc  eax
          jmp  printPrime
  done:   ret




The way isPrime is written, it will always have to report "not prime". Any number is divisible by 1 and by itself. Although you nicely avoid dividing by 1, you happily divide the number by itself because you have written:

INC     ECX
CMP     ECX, EAX
JG      prime
JMP     checkDivisor


The correct conditional jump would be JGE prime, or even JE prime since you're incrementing by 1 anyway.
In this proc, don't forget to preserve ECX or better still, use EDI instead of ECX.
The isPrime algorithm is very inefficient. I have prepared a much faster version of this in an answer I wrote for Checking prime numbers in 8086 assembly.
Look for the code snippet beneath "A fast check for primality".
Pay attention: the code is 16-bit but the explanations are universal. Ultimately the difference between AX and EAX is just the extra E...
